# CSS: Make a side scrolling panel with arrows

Tags: html, css, scroll

I've been searching around for something like this just using CSS, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'm making something very similar to a photo gallery, and what I'd like it a panel with a few icons in it. But say I had ten icons in a panel that only fit five - in which case I'd like to have arrows pointing right and left that let you scroll to the next five.

I know I can probably use the overflow:scroll option if I just wanted a nifty scrollbar, but what I'd really like is something where I press the right arrow, and the icons shift across.

If anyone could point out any tutorials, or know what I'm talking about, please let me know :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search around for a jQuery slider plugin, fill this one with the content you want and modify the styling for your needs. Some good options:

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SliderGallery/

You can also try HTML5/CSS3 like this:

http://codepen.io/Merri/details/eEBKp

With some modifications you'll be able to integrate it in your design/needs :)

Comment: Thankyou for that. The first link is very close to what I had in mind. However, I was hoping I could find something that didn't use jQuery. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can, ofcourse, make it yourself using javascript or html5/css3. I'll update my answer within a few seconds for you.

Comment: Thankyou! I can't believe I didn't find this. I'll have it running in now time.

Comment: No problem, glad I could point you in the right direction! Good luck with your project.